# Crash when running QT application on Ubuntu Server

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, server

I am seeing that if I run a QT application on Ubuntu desktop edition I am able to run the application.  If I take the same application and try and run it on Ubuntu server edition I am seeing a crash when starting the QT application.  So far I have seen that I need to set QT to render offscreen with setting this environmental variable:

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen
```

And then when I run the application I get this stack trace with the application crashing:

```
Thread 3 "hmi" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff7fa8700 (LWP 18084)]
0x00007fffdf88decb in ?? () from /Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fffdf88decb in ?? () from /Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so
#1  0x00007fffdf88e283 in ?? () from /Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so
#2  0x00007ffff399a78d in QOpenGLContext::create() () from /Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
#3  0x00007ffff41d2a67 in ?? () from /Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5
#4  0x00007ffff41d32d2 in ?? () from /Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5
#5  0x00007ffff39633ea in QWindow::event(QEvent*) () from /Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
#6  0x00007ffff4206553 in QQuickWindow::event(QEvent*) () from /Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5
#7  0x00007ffff4eb25ca in QCoreApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007ffff4eb2720 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007ffff3958c69 in QGuiApplicationPrivate::processExposeEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::ExposeEvent*) () from /Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
#10 0x00007ffff39597fd in QGuiApplicationPrivate::processWindowSystemEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::WindowSystemEvent*) () from /Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
#11 0x00007ffff393aad3 in QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
#12 0x00007fffdf88e3f0 in ?? () from /Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so
#13 0x00007fffe9eb3197 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#14 0x00007fffe9eb33f0 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#15 0x00007fffe9eb349c in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#16 0x00007ffff4f01f07 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#17 0x00007ffff4eb076a in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#18 0x00007ffff4eb85fd in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /Qt5.6.2/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
```

I take the same application and run with offscreen set and on the desktop edition I am not seeing the same crash.  I do not see much info about the QT library libqoffscreen.so and cannot find symbols for the prebuilt libraries to get a better stack trace.  Is there anything that I may need to install on the Ubuntu server to allow me to run this QT application?

Comment: Looks like there is a bug in this application. Installing other random applications is unlikely to make the bug go away.

Comment: Try running under calories

Comment: If there is a bug in the application why would it work on the desktop version though?

Answer (score 0):

You’re trying to use Qt Quick, and this won’t work with the offscreen platform, as there’s no OpenGL support there. I don’t understand why you’d want to run such an application headless – it won’t be useful, presumably. Since it your code, you shouldn’t be showing the GUI in the headless mode: either add a command option to start without the GUI, or disable the GUI code using compile options (e.g. a macro passed from the makefile).

Comment: So even though it is offscreen I am hooking up selenium to drive the GUI even though it is offscreen.  That way I can run some automated tests against the GUI but don't care if it is visible.  I guess this still doesn't answer why I am seeing in offscreen mode it is working on Ubuntu desktop version though.